# Display `Automatic` as well as custom Ticks in a plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

I have the following example data

```
os = {1, 3, 9, 11, 13, 17}; 
data = {0, -9.000050000000037`, -18.000100000000074`,
   -27.00015000000011`, -36.00020000000015`, -16.00020000000022`, 
   3.999799999999709`, 23.999799999999638`, 43.99979999999957`, 
   46.49974999999955`, 48.999699999999535`, 54.999749999999636`, 
   60.99979999999974`, 66.49984999999975`, 71.99989999999977`, 
   79.99989999999977`, 87.99989999999977`, 81.99939999999938`, 
   75.998899999999`, 69.99839999999861`, 63.997899999998225`, 
   79.4977499999973`, 94.99759999999637`, 107.49759999999637`, 
   119.99759999999637`, 138.99784999999693`, 157.9980999999975`, 
   153.49824999999836`, 148.99839999999924`, 155.49789999999885`, 
   161.99739999999846`, 175.49764999999834`, 188.99789999999822`};
```

And I make the following plot

```
ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Black, 
GridLines -> {(os - 1) 2 + 1, data[[(os - 1) 2 + 1]]}, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black]]
```

[image]

I would like the y-axis to show the automatic ticks as right now, as well as ticks at the grid line locations.

I tried adding the property `Ticks -> {Automatic, {Automatic, data[[(os - 1) 2 + 1]]}}`, but this gives a syntax error. What is the correct syntax to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`AxisObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject) to add additional ticks. For example, for the ticks on the horizontal axis:

```
ListLinePlot[
    data, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> Black, 
    GridLines -> {(os - 1) 2 + 1, data[[(os - 1) 2 + 1]]}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black],
    Epilog -> AxisObject[
        Line[{{0,0},{34,0}}], 
        {0,34}, 
        AxisStyle->Opacity[0],
        TickPositions->{{(os - 1) 2 + 1}}
    ]
]
```

[image]

For the vertical ticks, things are trickier, because [`ListLinePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot) automatically uses [`PlotRangeClipping`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping), which will clip the labels. The following will work, but won't clip any graphics elements that need to be clipped:

```
ListLinePlot[
    data, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> Black, 
    GridLines -> {(os - 1) 2 + 1, data[[(os - 1) 2 + 1]]}, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black],
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    ImagePadding->{{50,0},{10,10}},
    Epilog -> AxisObject[
        Line[{{0, -50}, {0, 200}}],
        {-50, 200},
        AxisStyle->Opacity[0],
        TickPositions->{{Round @ data[[(os-1) 2 + 1]]}}
    ],
    PlotRangeClipping->False
]
```

[image]

I used [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round) so that the labels aren't clipped by [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding). If you want to avoid [`Round`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Round), you will need to increase the image padding on the left. I also explicitly set the axis origins.

Comment: Thank you! I found that in this particular case `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Epilog -> { AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 0}, TickPositions -> {{(os - 1) 2 + 1}}], 
  AxisObject[{"Vertical", 0}, TickPositions -> {{Round@data[[(os - 1) 2 + 1]]}}]}` is sufficient to have all labels appear.

Comment: Looks like the PlotRangeClipping issue is a bug fixed in M13.